# Boundness of matrix $A^{\ast}$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $H_1\hookrightarrow H_2\hookrightarrow H_3$ be three Hilbert spaces. Consider a matrix $A$ such that $A\in\mathscr{B}(H_1, H_2)$, i.e. $A$ is bounded from $H_1$ to $H_2$. What I could say abou the matrix $A^{\ast}$? Does $A^{\ast}\in\mathscr{B}(H_2, H_3)$?

Could anyone please explain me if it is true or false?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$? If this is what you mean, $A^*$ is an element of $\mathscr{B}(H_2,H_1)$ (instead of  $\mathscr{B}(H_2,H_3)$), and we have $\|A\| = \|A^*\|$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint)).